# Comparison between an image from a database an a web camera live feed using opencv

Tags: opencv

Is there anyway/method to compare a live feed captured in a web camera and an image stored in a database?

Comment: There are a lot of method. How similar can we expect the images to be? Can you give examples?

Comment: for example, i have a picture stored in a database..
i edited that picture, put some stains there..
i want to compare the edited picture to the picture stored in the database.. If there is a difference between the two, the output would be "DIFFERENT PICTURE". something like that..
is it even possible to compare them pixel by pixel?

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between similar image but with slight differences or if there are slight differences, then it's ok?

Comment: I see you already got an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418049/comparison-between-an-image-from-a-database-an-a-web-camera-live-feed-using-open